# Do you capitalize words after mentioning a book with a punctuation mark in it?

Tags: punctuation, orthography

If someone uses the name of a book/object with punctuation in it, does one need to capitalize the word after?

Do I write:

> In the book *Who's Afraid of Virginia Woolf?* the main character...

Or

> In the book *Who's Afraid of Virginia Woolf?* The main character...

Comment: Are you starting a new sentence?

Comment: In other words - no, because the question mark is part of the title and doesn't affect the grammar of the sentence.

Comment: [There was a similar question about an even gnarlier title](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231289/quoting-title-with-a-question-and-ellipsis); it was closed as opinion-based (and the only answer agrees it's a matter of opinion) but everyone agrees on lower-casing the following word. [Here's the converse question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/600428/sentence-final-title-of-work-with-terminal-punctuation) about what to do if it's at the end of a sentence.